# workbox-google-analytics / service-worker offline analytics: "Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'sync' in undefined

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, service-worker, offline, workbox

I have seen that other similar questions have been asked, and that the error was having the analytics code in the main js file rather than the service-worker.js file. In this case all the code is in the service-worker.js file.

Setup: node 16.0.0 (also does the same with node 15.x.x), and static site built with eleventy

For google analytics I use the analytics.js file. Basically this with a few other options added:

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<script async src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'></script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

The service-worker.js code in question:

```
import * as googleAnalytics from 'workbox-google-analytics';
googleAnalytics.initialize({
  parameterOverrides: {
    cd1: 'offline',
  },
});
```

The service worker in general works absolutely fine. It has various routing routines, precache etc., and the google analytics code seems to do what it should. I can see items caching in IndexedDB when offline, and then the queue clearing when connectivity comes back. I can also see on my google analytics page hits for 'offline' as detailed in the parameterOverrides in the code above.

...so all would seem well, but in the console I still get the following:

```
service-worker.js?hash=4f292a2050:4259 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'sync' in undefined
at Queue._addSyncListener (service-worker.js?hash=4f292a2050:4259)
at new Queue (service-worker.js?hash=4f292a2050:4077)
at new BackgroundSyncPlugin (service-worker.js?hash=4f292a2050:4341)
at initialize (service-worker.js?hash=4f292a2050:4515)
at service-worker.js?hash=4f292a2050:4647
at service-worker.js?hash=4f292a2050:65
```

I have not run the service worker through terser yet, so it is readable for anyone who wants to have a look.

https://www.thetestspecimen.com/ (then look in dev tools-->application-->service-worker.js)

I should also note that if I use the standard:

```
googleAnalytics.initialize();
```

it still does the same thing.

Obviously something is amiss, but I can't figure out what. Any suggestions appreciated

Comment: "In this case all the code is in the service-worker.js file." << yes but your service-worker.js is then loaded into your main HTML with a script tag! So it is the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have seen that other similar questions have been asked, and that the
> error was having the analytics code in the main js file rather than
> the service-worker.js file. In this case all the code is in the
> service-worker.js file.

That is, in fact, what's going on here. The HTML for https://www.thetestspecimen.com/ includes

```
<script async="" defer="" src="/service-worker.js?hash=4afd6f55e2"></script>
```

which means that code which is meant to run in the context of the `ServiceWorkerGlobalScope` (in which [`self.registration` is defined](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/blob/4243caae91d9a2d117c1a10e4282f03c02fea059/packages/workbox-background-sync/src/Queue.ts#L371)) is instead being run in the `window` global scope, where `self.registration` is `undefined`. That is what's leading to the `Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'sync' in undefined` runtime error.

Just adjust your build to ensure that you don't end up with that `<script>` tag executing your service worker code as part of your main app, and you should be fine.

Comment: Well to be honest I'm glad it was something so simple. Thanks for the quick reply Jeff. Sometimes the obvious is not so obvious when you are trying to find a problem!